# NoSQL architecture for app like Google Reader

Tags: mongodb, couchdb, cassandra, redis, riak

What NoSQL architecture would you use for application like Google Reader (one to one copy)?

I consider MongoDB, Cassandra, CouchDB, Redis, HBase and Riak.

Comment: This question needs a little more substance before it's useful.

Comment: I started writing an answer then I realized that based on such a generic requirement you could make a case for any of these. I would personally choose MongoDB - it works great for storing documents and inserts are very cheap/fast (and with an app like this you will end up doing more inserts then reads). But I could make a case for CouchDB, Redis, or Riak as well.

Answer (score 2):

Easy answer, use the one you're most comfortable with.

The more complex answer really lies in the details of what Google Reader can do. One feature that you'll probably want is multiple indexes.

Each RSS entry is going to have a unique key, a user, a ts, a read flag and some categories. When dealing with document-oriented or key-value databases, it's generally easy to get the key. But what's the first query you're really going to run? List by user, ts, read.

Well, that's going to need a secondary index. AFAIK **riak** and **redis** don't support this at all. **CouchDB** and **Cassandra** seem to have some workarounds (views), but it's still not easy. **MongoDB** supports secondary indexes "[out of the box](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes)".

So right off the bat, you're making it easy to get it working with MongoDB.

Mongo also has a series of [atomic operations](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Atomic+Operations) that makes is easier to update data asynchronously.

Comment: +1, the technology is almost always secondary to the the programmer and the expertise you have.

Comment: But for the record, CouchDB views *are* secondary indexes!